# JavaScript infinite loop when drowning circles

Tags: javascript

My exercise is to create 5 circles with random colors, size, position.
I'm almost there but I don't understand why it keep in a infinite loop.

I tried to put the variables like global but it wont generate more than one random number.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1080, 920);   
}


function draw() {

  background(224);
  for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
      var rdnRadius = int(random(0,500));
      var rdnColorX = int(random(0,300));
      var rdnColorY = int(random(0,400)); 
      var rdnColorZ = int(random(0,100));
      var rdnX = int(random(0,500));
      var rdnY = int(random(0,500));
     dibuixarElipse(rdnColorX, rdnColorY, rdnColorY, rdnX, rdnY, 
rdnRadius);
  }
}



 function dibuixarElipse(colorX, colorY, colorZ, x, y, radius) {

        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke(colorX, colorY, colorZ);
        noFill();
        ellipse(x, y, radius); 
    }
```

I expect 5 circles with random colors, positions and sizes every time I refresh my html. I'm getting infinite loop.

Comment: You didn't show us `dibuixarElipse` - are you calling from that function recursively to `draw()` ?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What does ellipse function is for? the easy way would be add console.log in dibuixarElipse function to see what is going on in there

Comment: Your partial code doesn't give much clue. Check implementations for functions triggered from dibuixarElipse block. You might be calling draw() function from one of those functions.

Comment: Find all the places where `draw()` is being called. If this is within some framework you should specify what that is, especially if your framework is what is calling `setup()` and `draw()`. It may be, if you are given the opportunity draw each frame, that you should simply keep track, "globally" or otherwise, of whether you have already drawn your circles.

Comment: Doesn't the draw() function works like a loop always calling itself in p5? Do it in the setup() function instead.